# Is it safe to change `SKNode`s in a gesture recognizer action method?

Tags: ios, multithreading, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, gestures

Apple states in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscenedelegate :

> Modifying SpriteKit objects outside of the ordained callbacks (a
>   background queue or anything else non-main-thread) can result in
>   concurrency related problems. **Even dispatching work on the main thread
>   asynchronously or at a later time is risky** because the closure is
>   likely to be done outside of the timeframe SpriteKit expects. If
>   you're experiencing a segmentation fault or other type of crash
>   occurring deep within the SpriteKit framework, there's a good chance
>   your code is modifying a SpriteKit object outside of the normal
>   callbacks.

I'm using gesture recognizers to interact with my sprite kit objects. A simple example would be to add a SKAction to a node when the user tapped an object:

```
func tapAction(gr:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    scene.childNode(withName: "balloon")!.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2))
}
```

Despite the fact that this "just works" for the moment, I'm afraid that this does not work in more complicated cases.

Is there any hint from Apple that this is allowed? Or do I really have to defer the modification of the SpritKit object from the gesture action to an ordained callback?

Comment: you are safe,  you are just assigning an action, that is going to run during the normal sprite kit updates

Comment: this seems totally normal to me. Except the force unwrap is problematic if your balloon gets popped or something :P I would feel wary if this gesture removed or changed physicsBodies (because that always causes issues in didBegin) in which case having this set a flag that will be interpreted in your gamescene may be ideal.

Comment: @Fluidity the "balloon" gets never removed. I know how to handle optionals :-)

Comment: haha ok, I didn't click on your name so I didn't know if your rep was from like java or something.. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are safe, you are just assigning an action. That is going to run during the normal sprite kit updates

if you were manipulating the actual object, or removing a node,  you would come into problems.  Let's say you tap to remove a node.  This tap happens right before `didContactBegin`.  `didContactBegin` would expect a node, but alas, you removed it, so it will crash.

If you want to feel safe about this,  then set up a queue to fire at the beginning of your update.

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
   public typealias Closure = ()->()
   public var processOnUpdate = [Closure]()


   override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
       proceseOnUpdate.forEach{$0()}
       processOnUpdate = [Closure]()
       ....//do other stuff
   }
}

//SKView Code
func tapAction(gr:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    scene.processOnUpdate.append(
    { 
       scene.childNode(withName: "balloon")!.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 2))
    }}

}
```

My apologies if this does not run the first time,  I am not on a Mac now to test this.

Comment: isn't the force unwrap unsafe if the balloon is removed at some point?

Comment: @Fluidity, Absolutely, that is up to Klaas to decide how to handle that,  maybe the balloon never gets removed,  I have no idea.

Comment: He will at least have caused the crash and know where it lies,  unlike it crashing somewhere in the framework and having no idea where it is happening.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for your extensive answer and thoughts! Seems reasonable.

Comment: Do you know why "dispatching work on the main thread asynchronously or at a later time is risky"? Your example of `didContactBegin` made it very clear why changing nodes asynchronously is bad but I can't think of a situation where making a change on the main thread would be "risky". Do you know of any such situation?

Comment: @rayaantaneja you might run into a situation where your async call is never done because the main thread is on some kind of infinite loop.  You could also end up in a situation where the main thread is looking for the async call to finish, while at the same time your async call is waiting for the main thread to finish, locking your process up.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I had a similar question regarding asynchronously dispatching to the main queue being risky due to it potentially executing "outside the frame SpriteKit expects". I feel infinite loops and deadlock like you've mentioned is not specific to SpriteKit (please correct me if I'm wrong). I've elaborated my main concerns in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325135/why-is-it-risky-to-dispatch-work-asynchronously-on-the-main-thread-in-spriteki. If you could shed any light on this I'll very grateful.